# C++ List Objects Error

Tags: c++

I have read posts about using lists and pointer to objects. However I cannot figure it out. I will share my files. Hopefully someone can help me.

The specific problem is done exactly how our lecturer wrote of board. I took picture and am using it, but doesn't work. Its not easy find solution to exactly the issue.

The issue is the first file, `Game.h`. Says next error for each one of these. No visible errors appear before compiling. What am I doing wrong ? Any help much appreciated. I have also added list of errors below all files at bottom of post in case they help

```
GameObject* P_Player = new Player();
GameObject* P_Enemy_1 = new Enemy();
GameObject* P_Enemy_2 = new Enemy();
GameObject* P_Enemy_3 = new Enemy();
GameObject* P_Enemy_4 = new Enemy();
```

The compiler reports:

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     C2027   use of undefined type 'Player'  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.h 44
> ```

Game.h

```
//Game.h
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void init();
private:
    //Game objects, List and list iterator
    list <GameObject*> listOfObjects;
    list <GameObject*>::iterator listOfObjects_iterator;


    GameObject* P_Player = new Player();
    GameObject* P_Enemy_1 = new Enemy();
    GameObject* P_Enemy_2 = new Enemy();
    GameObject* P_Enemy_3 = new Enemy();
    GameObject* P_Enemy_4 = new Enemy();
};
```

Game.cpp file

```
//Game.cpp
#include "Game.h"
#include <array>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

Game::Game(){}
Game::~Game(){}

void Game::init()
{
    int array[23][23];
    int randomInt;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int serielID = 1;

    int x;
    int y;
    for (x = 0; x < 24; x++) { for (y = 0; y < 24; y++) { array[x][x] = 0; } }

    listOfObjects.push_back(P_Player);
    listOfObjects.push_back(P_Enemy_1);
    listOfObjects.push_back(P_Enemy_2);
    listOfObjects.push_back(P_Enemy_3);
    listOfObjects.push_back(P_Enemy_4);

    for (listOfObjects_iterator = listOfObjects.begin(); listOfObjects_iterator != listOfObjects.end(); listOfObjects_iterator++)
    {
        do
        {
            x = rand() % 23;
            y = rand() % 23;
        }while (array[y][x] == 0);
        x++;y++;

        (*listOfObjects_iterator)->spawn(to_string(serielID), 100, 1, y, x);
        serielID++;
    }
}
```

GameObject.h

```
//GameObject.h
#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class GameObject
{
    public:
        void spawn(string typeID, int health, int speed, int x, int y);

    protected:
        string m_typeID;
        int m_health;
        int m_speed;
        signed int m_x;
        signed int m_y;
        bool alive;
};
```

Player.h

```
//Player.h
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Player : public GameObject
{

public:
    Player();
    ~Player();


private:
    int m_damage;
    string player = "player";
};
```

Player.cpp

```
//Player.cpp
#include "Player.h"
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

Player::Player(){}

Player::~Player(){}
```

Enemy.h

```
//Enemy.h
#include "GameObject.h"

using namespace std;

class Enemy : public GameObject
{

public:
    Enemy();
    ~Enemy();


private:
    int m_damage;
    string enemy = "enemy";

};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
//Enemy.cpp
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

Enemy::Enemy() {}

Enemy::~Enemy() {}
```

Errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2297   '-': illegal, right operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)' MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   124 
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Player'  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.h 44  
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Enemy'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.h 45  
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Enemy'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.h 46  
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Enemy'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.h 47  
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Enemy'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.h 48  
Error   C2107   illegal index, indirection not allowed  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   73  
Error   C2107   illegal index, indirection not allowed  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   75  
Error   C3867   'Player::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   109 
Error   C3867   'Player::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   114 
Error   C3867   'Player::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   118 
Error   C3867   'Player::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   125 
Error   C2011   'Player': 'class' type redefinition MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\player.h   6   
Error   C3867   'GameObject::objectType': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   72  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::isAlive': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   141 
Error   C3867   'GameObject::getHealth': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   109 
Error   C3867   'GameObject::getHealth': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   114 
Error   C3867   'GameObject::getHealth': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   118 
Error   C3867   'GameObject::getHealth': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   124 
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   52  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   53  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   54  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   55  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   56  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   73  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_Y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   75  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_X': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   52  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_X': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   53  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_X': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   54  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_X': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   55  
Error   C3867   'GameObject::GameObject_X': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   56  
Error   C2660   'Game::battle': function does not take 0 arguments  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\main.cpp   69  
Error   C3867   'Enemy::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   109 
Error   C3867   'Enemy::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   114 
Error   C3867   'Enemy::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   118 
Error   C3867   'Enemy::giveDamage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   124 
Error   C2011   'Enemy': 'class' type redefinition  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\enemy.h    5   
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'std::string (__thiscall GameObject::* )(void)'  MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   72  
Error   C2446   '<=': no conversion from 'int (__thiscall Player::* )(void)' to 'int'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   109 
Error   C2446   '<=': no conversion from 'int (__thiscall Player::* )(void)' to 'int'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   114 
Error   C2446   '<=': no conversion from 'int (__thiscall Player::* )(void)' to 'int'   MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   118 
Error   C2297   '<=': illegal, right operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)'    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   109 
Error   C2297   '<=': illegal, right operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)'    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   114 
Error   C2297   '<=': illegal, right operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)'    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   118 
Error   C2296   '<=': illegal, left operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)' MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   109 
Error   C2296   '<=': illegal, left operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)' MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   114 
Error   C2296   '<=': illegal, left operand has type 'int (__thiscall Enemy::* )(void)' MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   118 
Error   C2297   '-': illegal, right operand has type 'int (__thiscall Player::* )(void)'    MyGame  c:\users\gaddmaster\desktop\c++\animated assignment\game\game.cpp   125
```

Comment: Crom that's a lot of code. Bets you can work that down to an [mcve]. Not only will you likely find the error yourself while producing the MCVE, but you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Strongly recommend using some sort of [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: Ok i just read about the minimal, complete and verifiable thing. I'm going to remake it now smaller. Thanks very much for advice. Ill be back with edit in 10 minutes

Comment: Yes missing them include tags, let me add them and try. I totally forgot about them things

Comment: Also keep an eye out for [Multi Byte Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding). Some of the characters you define as `char`s are too big to be `char`s. You can use `wchar`, wide characters, but for now you're probably better off sticking to the standard 1 byte character sets like ASCII.

Comment: The include Gaurds seems to have helped, still loads of errors though. Working on it now still, make minimal question also

Comment: Yes including guards and adding endless missed () at end of functions was problem. 
Thanks very much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you call some getter as a property (ex: `player->getHealth` in `game.cpp:109`).
It's a method, so you need parenthesis (ex: `player->getHealth()`).

Then add Header Guard in your `.h` files, like this:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H_
#define FILENAME_H_

// header file content here

#endif // !FILENAME_H_
```

You can modify a bit the syntax, but put the good filename in the macro. This will prevent to double include a header file.

After doing it, update your post if there are some errors, there are too many right now.

Comment: Ya wow missing so many () at end of function, totally forgot about them. Virtual Studio for some reason has this functionality that pops up the function list to pick from to save time typing it and also showing us whats available. However it leaves out the () so this is why i keep missing them i thinks

Comment: Haha that was it, between Guards and adding () . Thanks man. I'm going to finish making minimal version

Comment: Thanks so much Ludonope